# PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" on the production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using capistrano gem for deployment and when I deploy the app my migration is running successfully. But when I tries to run seed file it is giving me error.
Following is my databse.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  username: postgres
  password: 12345678
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db_production
  username: postgres
  password: 12345678
```

Comment: The error says it all. You can't connect to the database because the credentials are incorrect   for the postgres user. Are they correct?

Comment: Yes the credentials are correct, I have checked that

Comment: You don't happen to be using docker do you?

Comment: No, I am not using docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having LINODE server and was facing this issue.

I noticed that when I run `rails c` in current directory after login to the server using ssh, it loads the development environment and that's why it is giving me authentication error.

We have to run `bundle exec rails console production` so it loads the production environment and it's working